# Changing AWS ECS TaksDefinitions environment variables through rest API

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, environment-variables, amazon-ecs

I have an AWS Java ECS application and every time that I need to change some environment variables in production, I need to use Breaking Glass.

How can I change those variables using a Spring Boot rest API? Do you guys have some examples and docs?

I'm looking for some examples this moment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.